# PHP fopen stream parallel

Tags: php, stream, parallel-processing, fopen

I have php file `check_device.php` that ckecks device (switch) remotely for some options by telnet.

In html+jQuery I load it with

```
$.get('check_device.php?host=xyz', function(data)
{
    $("#device_1").html( $("#device_1").html()+data);
});
```

I have many "loads" like this in html. But its too slow, it always goes one after another, and every load takes about 7sec (so 3 loads takes 3x7 = ~21sec). It looks like every instance of "check_device.php" waits until previous instances are done.

I thought if I will load it through jQuery Ajax it would be parallel and asynchronous and it would be quicker.

Is there any option in php to allow parallel stream fopen?

Comment: I guess it should be faster when you keep connection's alive with your webserver. 

And start asking all data in one time and output it with json and split it in your jQuery.

Comment: But then I couldnt make the requests parallel, because in PHP I cant make parallel readings from different remote devices.
Idea was to make this requests parallel so they dont have to wait for previous requests to be done.